Why do I observe an ICMP Destination Port Unreachable (Type 3, Code 3) when GRE tunneling with iproute2?
I am testing the native GRE tunneling functionality of iproute2 in linux network namespaces. The simulated setup involves 3 different namespaces with 2 bridges and 4 veth pairs.
Please see the section below to fully recreate the setup.
One network namespace contains a purely IPv6 network with a single veth interface, another contains a purely IPv4 network with a single veth interface, and a third has a dual stack network with two different veth interfaces (IPv4 and IPv6) that are contained.
The two IPv6 veth peers are connected to one bridge while the other two IPv4 veth peers are connected to the other bridge. Using this configuration I am able to set up a GRE tunnel on the IPv4 network namespace with the remote address of the IPv4 veth interface in the dual stack network namespace.
I also updated the routes in the IPv4 network namespace to use the GRE tunnel device for all IPv6 addresses. However, when performing a single ping to the IPv6 address, I observe the packet is encapsulated and sent correctly using GRE (Ethernet > IPv4 > GRE > IPv6 > ICMPv6) but an ICMP Destination Port Unreachable (type 3, code 3) message is automatically returned. When testing TCP connections I get the same response.
What does this error mean in this context? Is there some misconfiguration? I should note that from the remote network namespace I am able to ping the IPv6 destination address without any issues. I am fairly new to GRE tunneling so there may be some conceptual misunderstanding.

To recreate the setup you can run the following script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

# Create network namespaces
ip netns add sim-ipv4-stack
ip netns add sim-ipv6-stack
ip netns add sim-dual-stack

# Create and configure bridge links
ip link add sim-ipv4-br0 type bridge
ip link add sim-ipv6-br0 type bridge

ip link set dev sim-ipv4-br0 up
ip link set dev sim-ipv6-br0 up

# Create and configure veth links
ip link add sim-ipv4-veth0 type veth peer sim-ipv4-veth0p
ip link add sim-ipv6-veth0 type veth peer sim-ipv6-veth0p
ip link add sim-dual-veth0 type veth peer sim-dual-veth0p
ip link add sim-dual-veth1 type veth peer sim-dual-veth1p

ip link set dev sim-ipv4-veth0 master sim-ipv4-br0
ip link set dev sim-ipv6-veth0 master sim-ipv6-br0
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth0 master sim-ipv4-br0
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth1 master sim-ipv6-br0

ip link set dev sim-ipv4-veth0p netns sim-ipv4-stack
ip link set dev sim-ipv6-veth0p netns sim-ipv6-stack
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth0p netns sim-dual-stack
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth1p netns sim-dual-stack

ip link set dev sim-ipv4-veth0 up
ip link set dev sim-ipv6-veth0 up
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth0 up
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth1 up

ip -n sim-ipv4-stack link set dev sim-ipv4-veth0p up
ip -n sim-ipv6-stack link set dev sim-ipv6-veth0p up
ip -n sim-dual-stack link set dev sim-dual-veth0p up
ip -n sim-dual-stack link set dev sim-dual-veth1p up

SIM_IPV4_ADDR=172.20.0.4
SIM_IPV6_ADDR=fc00::6
SIM_DUAL_IPV4_ADDR=172.20.0.14
SIM_DUAL_IPV6_ADDR=fc00::16
SIM_IPV4_TUN6_ADDR=fc00::4

ip -n sim-ipv4-stack addr add $SIM_IPV4_ADDR/24 dev sim-ipv4-veth0p
ip -n sim-ipv6-stack addr add $SIM_IPV6_ADDR/64 dev sim-ipv6-veth0p
ip -n sim-dual-stack addr add $SIM_DUAL_IPV4_ADDR/24 dev sim-dual-veth0p
ip -n sim-dual-stack addr add $SIM_DUAL_IPV6_ADDR/64 dev sim-dual-veth1p

# Configure GRE tunnel
ip -n sim-ipv4-stack tunnel add sim-ipv4-gre0 mode gre remote $SIM_DUAL_IPV4_ADDR
ip -n sim-ipv4-stack addr add $SIM_IPV4_TUN6_ADDR/64 dev sim-ipv4-gre0
ip -n sim-ipv4-stack link set dev sim-ipv4-gre0 up

set +x

To tear down this simulated setup you can then run:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

# Destroy veth links
ip link del sim-ipv4-veth0
ip link del sim-ipv6-veth0
ip link del sim-dual-veth0
ip link del sim-dual-veth1

# Destroy bridge links
ip link del sim-ipv4-br0
ip link del sim-ipv6-br0

# Destroy namespaces
ip netns del sim-ipv4-stack
ip netns del sim-ipv6-stack
ip netns del sim-dual-stack

set +x

Once you've successfully created the setup you can enter the sim-ipv4-stack namespace using:
ip netns exec sim-ipv4-stack bash

You should have two separate terminals open in that namespace, one for observing traffic and another for sending traffic.
In order to observe the traffic you should download and install termshark. Once you have it available to you on the host you can run termshark from within the simulated namespace as follows:
ip netns exec sim-ipv4-stack bash
termshark -i sim-ipv4-veth0p

You can then send traffic from the other shell in the sim-ipv4-stack namespace using:
ip netns exec sim-ipv4-stack bash
ping -6 -c 1 fc00::16

Looking at termshark, you should observe an encapsulated ICMPv6 packet being sent initially and then a response ICMP packet with the type/code destination port unreachable.
I am not sure exactly why the destination is considered unreachable because you can ping the IPv6 namespace from the dual stack namespace as follows:
ip netns exec sim-dual-stack ping -6 -c 10 fc00::6

Similarly, you can ping the IPv4 namespace from the dual stack namespace as follows:
ip netns exec sim-dual-stack ping -c 10 172.20.0.4


Following the answer from Tom below, I have updated the setup script to the one below:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

# Create network namespaces
ip netns add sim-ipv4-stack
ip netns add sim-ipv6-stack
ip netns add sim-dual-stack

# Create and configure bridge links
ip link add sim-ipv4-br0 type bridge
ip link add sim-ipv6-br0 type bridge

ip link set dev sim-ipv4-br0 up
ip link set dev sim-ipv6-br0 up

# Create and configure veth links
ip link add sim-ipv4-veth0 type veth peer sim-ipv4-veth0p
ip link add sim-ipv6-veth0 type veth peer sim-ipv6-veth0p
ip link add sim-dual-veth0 type veth peer sim-dual-veth0p
ip link add sim-dual-veth1 type veth peer sim-dual-veth1p

ip link set dev sim-ipv4-veth0 master sim-ipv4-br0
ip link set dev sim-ipv6-veth0 master sim-ipv6-br0
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth0 master sim-ipv4-br0
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth1 master sim-ipv6-br0

ip link set dev sim-ipv4-veth0p netns sim-ipv4-stack
ip link set dev sim-ipv6-veth0p netns sim-ipv6-stack
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth0p netns sim-dual-stack
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth1p netns sim-dual-stack

ip link set dev sim-ipv4-veth0 up
ip link set dev sim-ipv6-veth0 up
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth0 up
ip link set dev sim-dual-veth1 up

ip -n sim-ipv4-stack link set dev sim-ipv4-veth0p up
ip -n sim-ipv6-stack link set dev sim-ipv6-veth0p up
ip -n sim-dual-stack link set dev sim-dual-veth0p up
ip -n sim-dual-stack link set dev sim-dual-veth1p up

ip -n sim-ipv4-stack link set dev lo up
ip -n sim-ipv6-stack link set dev lo up
ip -n sim-dual-stack link set dev lo up

SIM_IPV4_ADDR=172.20.0.4
SIM_IPV6_ADDR=fc00::6
SIM_DUAL_IPV4_ADDR=172.20.0.14
SIM_DUAL_IPV6_ADDR=fc00::16
SIM_IPV4_TUN6_ADDR=fc00::4
SIM_DUAL_TUN6_ADDR=fc00::26

ip -n sim-ipv4-stack addr add $SIM_IPV4_ADDR/24 dev sim-ipv4-veth0p
ip -n sim-ipv6-stack addr add $SIM_IPV6_ADDR/128 dev sim-ipv6-veth0p
ip -n sim-dual-stack addr add $SIM_DUAL_IPV4_ADDR/24 dev sim-dual-veth0p
ip -n sim-dual-stack addr add $SIM_DUAL_IPV6_ADDR/128 dev sim-dual-veth1p

# Configure GRE tunnel
ip -n sim-ipv4-stack tunnel add sim-ipv4-gre0 mode gre remote $SIM_DUAL_IPV4_ADDR
ip -n sim-ipv4-stack addr add $SIM_IPV4_TUN6_ADDR/128 dev sim-ipv4-gre0
ip -n sim-ipv4-stack link set dev sim-ipv4-gre0 up
ip -n sim-ipv4-stack route add $SIM_DUAL_TUN6_ADDR dev sim-ipv4-gre0
ip -n sim-ipv4-stack route add $SIM_IPV6_ADDR dev sim-ipv4-gre0

ip -n sim-dual-stack tunnel add sim-dual-gre0 mode gre remote $SIM_IPV4_ADDR
ip -n sim-dual-stack addr add $SIM_DUAL_TUN6_ADDR/128 dev sim-dual-gre0
ip -n sim-dual-stack link set dev sim-dual-gre0 up
ip -n sim-dual-stack route add $SIM_IPV4_TUN6_ADDR dev sim-dual-gre0
ip -n sim-dual-stack route add $SIM_IPV6_ADDR dev sim-dual-veth1p

ip -n sim-ipv6-stack route add $SIM_DUAL_IPV6_ADDR dev sim-ipv6-veth0p
ip -n sim-ipv6-stack route add $SIM_IPV4_TUN6_ADDR dev sim-ipv6-veth0p via $SIM_DUAL_IPV6_ADDR

# Ensure that forwarding is enabled (necessary only for the sim-dual-stack namespace).
ip -n sim-ipv4-stack netns exec sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
ip -n sim-ipv4-stack netns exec sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
ip -n sim-ipv6-stack netns exec sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
ip -n sim-ipv6-stack netns exec sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
ip -n sim-dual-stack netns exec sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
ip -n sim-dual-stack netns exec sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

set +x

I had to ensure that forwarding was enabled in the sim-dual-stack namespace (this wasn't the case even though forwarding was enabled in the host) using:
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

Once I did this, I could successfully ping the sim-ipv6-stack from the sim-ipv4-stack namespaces using:
ip netns exec sim-ipv4-stack ping -6 -c 10 fc00::6

The updated script includes the sysctl updates for each of the network namespaces.

Can you complete your description with a reproducible setup? Check what it means there: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@A.B I have fully described the setup. Is this sufficient to understand the problem and provide a solution?

First of all, you have set up only one end of the tunnel:
ip -n sim-ipv4-stack tunnel add sim-ipv4-gre0 mode gre remote $SIM_DUAL_IPV4_ADDR

You would need to set up the other end in sim-dual-stack:
ip -n sim-dual-stack tunnel add sim-dual-gre0 mode gre remote $SIM_IPV4_ADDR
ip -n sim-dual-stack addr add $SIM_DUAL_TUN6_ADDR/128 dev sim-dual-gre0 # You probably shouldn't use /64 here
ip -n sim-dual-stack link set dev sim-dual-gre0 up

And you would need a "host route" for SIM_IPV4_TUN6_ADDR in sim-dual-stack as well:
ip -6 r add fc00::4/128 dev sim-dual-gre0

Note that SIM_DUAL_TUN6_ADDR is not defined in your script. But indeed, you don't exactly need to assign an IP on sim-dual-gre0, given your current "idea". (Actually, I suppose it has more to do with the fact that GRE tunnels are L3 / point-to-point tunnels.)
By "idea" I mean the fact that you were using one single subnet (fc00::16/64) for both the "IPv6 half" of your setup and the GRE tunnel (that is "nested" in the "IPv4 half"). Since I don't know what exactly your ultimate goal is (well, my guess is that you want to use sim-dual-stack as some sort of "IPv6 relay" for sim-ipv4-stack), I suppose I should stop here, but you should be aware that hosts in sim-ipv6-stack will have problem "locating" SIM_IPV4_TUN6_ADDR, at least until you set up e.g. "NDP proxy" (assuming there's such a thing) whatsoever in sim-dual-stack.
P.S. Since GRE tunnels are L3 / point-to-point tunnels, apparently just like the case of IPv4, in which ARP is not leveraged, for IPv6 NDP would not be leveraged either. In other words, anything routed into the tunnel will just go to the other end, and no router / gateway needs to be specified in any route. (I could be wrong though, since I don't really know IPv6.)

This looks to almost resolve the issue. One thing that doesn't seem to work is the forwarding of the GRE packet from the sim-dual-stack network namespace. I observe the encapsulated packet arriving on the sim-dual-veth0p interface and the decapsulated packet on the sim-dual-gre0 interface, however, I don't observe the packet being forwarded to the sim-ipv6-stack namespace via the sim-dual-veth1p interface. As you suggested I have updated the IPv6 prefixes and routing tables and edited my original question to include the new setup script. Note I have forwarding enabled on my system.

It turns out that although I enabled IPv6 forwarding on the host machine, IPv6 forwarding was not enabled in the sim-dual-stack namespace (not sure why exactly). Once I enabled it, I could successfully ping the sim-ipv6-stack from the sim-ipv4-stack using ip netns exec sim-ipv4-stack ping -6 -c 10 fc00::6. Since the IPv6 traffic is being routed I don't think that you need to be concerned with NDP in this case. The routing tables must be correctly configured though. Thank you for the answer.

Network namespaces also provide isolation for network-related kernel configuration parameters located in /proc/net/, /sys/class/net/, and /proc/sys/net/. The latter is what is used by sysctl which explains why IPv6 forwarding needs to be reconfigured (IPv4 forwarding is enabled by default is seems). This is documented on the network_namespaces man page.
